# Increase the intensity of heatmap points in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm using the Google Map v3 API to create a map showing markers and also a heat map. However when I switch over to the heat map mode the intensity of the discrete points is often too low for them to show up on the map. E.g:

[image: markers vs heapmap in Google Maps]

What is the best way to increase the intensity of each point so they they individually show up more like the groups of points above the 'Budapest' label?

Here is my heapmap code:

```
var latLongArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(latLongPoints);
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: latLongArray,
  map: map,
  radius: 20
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same problem here. did you got an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using opacity: 1 and set heatmap on the map object in the following line. Ex:

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
              data: heatMapData,
              radius: 20,
              opacity: 1
              });

heatmap.setMap(map);
```